# MS Access ADO recordset and two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, ms-access, recordset

I have a MS Access database. I want to get records and then write to two dimensional array. I can but I think recordset memory area and array memory area same. Because if I close recordset, I cant access arrays values.

> Error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class variant could not be
>   converted to string in ...

```
$databaselocation = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "ornek.mdb"; 
$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection') or exit('Cannot start ADO.'); 
$conn->Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=$databaselocation");

$SQL1 = "SELECT * from konu";
$rs = new com("ADODB.RecordSet") or die("Recordset cant create!"); 
$rs->Open($SQL1,$conn,1,3); 
$say =  $rs->RecordCount();
echo "Row Counts: " . $say . "<br><br>";

$dizi = array(array());


for($a=0; $a<$say; $a++)
{
    $dizi[$a][0] = $rs[0];
    $dizi[$a][1] = $rs[1];
    $rs->MoveNext;
}

$rs->Close(); $conn->Close();
$rs = null; $conn = null; 

echo $dizi[0][0];     // this line ERROR  same below

for($a=0; $a<$say; $a++)
{
    echo $dizi[$a][0] . " - " . $dizi[$a][1] . "<br>";    // ERROR
}
```

Comment: Can you show/print $dizi data. print_r($dizi);

Comment: Indeed, is `$dizi` empty or not? Run `var_dump($dizi)`. Curious, do you not have [PDO-ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php) to connect to MS Access with a PHP API rather than COM interface?

Answer (score 0):

In `$rs` you don't have string value, but special `COM` object. Usually it is automatically converted to `string`. In this case, in any cell you have some strange value, eg a formula.

Try [variant_get_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.variant-get-type.php) and [Constants list](http://php.net/manual/en/com.constants.php) and check `$rs[0]`, `$rs[1]` before use.

And if I'm remember you should use `$rs->fields[0]` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/fields-collection-ado). (Yes, you use this methods)

Comment: thank you for your answer. i solved. i have string data in database but not automatically converted to string. i cast variant object to string. $dizi[$a][0]=(string)$rs[0];

Comment: Is your query a one column resultset? I am with @bato3, that's strange no *fields* property or named field is needed.

Comment: @Parfait both ADO and DAO recordsets support the `rs(fieldnum)` syntax to access fields (you shouldn't use it imho since I prefer explicit code). As for the answer, the actual proper way to do this is `$rs[0]->Value` or `$rs->fields[0]->Value` as far as I know. The value property should just be a string, and not need further casting.

Answer (score 0):

i solved just now. when i cast variant object to string its worked as 
$dizi[$a][0]=(string)$rs[0];